# Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu 14.04. -Access Forbidden Error 403

Tags: apache, ubuntu, vhosts

Sorry if my explanations are uncomplete or missformed, I'm new to Ubuntu. And not really a sharp computer user (just a frontend developper):

I'm trying to setup a vhost on my computer but I keep getting a 403 in my browsere evr ytmie I rty to reach http://mywebsite.local and apache2 error logs keeps showing :

```
(13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:48889] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/media/leonsayshi/DATAS') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

I'd like my working folder to be inside /media/leonsayshi/DATAS/www (where DATAS is a partition I've mounted) and a *ls -l* command in my DATAS/ and www/ shows :

```
drwxrwxrwx 5 leonsayshi leonsayshi  4096 mars  21 13:13 DATAS
```

and

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 leonsayshi leonsayshi  4096 mars  21 14:55 www
```

Here is the content of my mywebsite.local.conf file (it has been enabled using sudo a2ensite mywebsite.local.conf) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mywebsite.local
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.local
    DocumentRoot /media/leonsayshi/DATAS/www/mywebsite/www/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /media/leonsayshi/DATAS/www/mywebsite/www/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride FileInfo
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas, or any infos missing ? 
Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Sorry by my bad english, i have the same problem (for that i read your problem and i answer for others that read this), my solution:
in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf put the

```
<Directory ..bla..bla...bla    
</Directory>
```

that you have in the mywebsite.local.conf